How to configure webhooks on developer.facebook Instagram API
API set up with Instagram Login.
Seeing the error in the attached screenshot.

The callback URL is a Railway.app domain

The verify token is a unique code that is self generated.

After entering these details, we should see a GET request on our server logs - I do not see anything.


And I receive an error code: The callback URL or verify token couldn't be validated.  Please verify the provided information or try again later.
More information: https://developers.facebook.com/community/threads/1460022321208053/?post_id=1460022324541386
we tried this multiple times over different days, and tried different length codes with varying characters.

If you don't even see any access log entry on your end, then Facebook probably could not reach your system at all. Have you tried to put a page of your site/app through https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/, to see what that has to say? (Don't worry if it shows open graph meta data missing, this is just to test if Facebook has a general problem connecting in this case.)

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
